# RTSP stream client based on Java

Tags: java, javafx, client, rtsp

Could someone explain me how can I include rtsp stream(from my IP camera, which uses user and passwd auth) in my java based application?

Are there any free libraries that could do the trick?

At this moment I've made a lot of research and the idea I've got is to use favaFx webView to open web page which would be generated by FFmpeg running on Ubuntu server. The only problem is that I don't really know how to tell the FFmpeg that this is my rtsp link and just give me some kind of HLS link to put in webView of javaFx.

If you know any simple solution how to make a java frame with rtsp stream please share it with me.